# How to add string to the end of a file without '\n'?

Tags: scripts

`echo "xxx" >> file_a` is similar to what I want.

But it always attach string with a new line.

If I just want to attach string without a new line,

How to do it?

Thank you~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `printf` builtin bash function

```
printf "xxx" >> file
```

or the `-n` option to `echo`, that suppress the newline.

Comment: printf is not only a Bash builtin, there's `/usr/bin/printf` too. Unlike the `-n` option of echo `printf` is definede by POSIX so it's usually the better choice.

Comment: @Florian Diesch: I know, but we are talking about *Ubuntu*, where the default shell is `bash`, and where `echo` has the `-n` option, so it is not so important as it could be on a generic unix/linux site. Moreover, also `sh`'s `echo` has `-n` option, so it is better to suggest alternatives that to be so radical, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Use printf:

```
printf "xxx" >> file_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Small variation on the theme, although somewhat verbose

```
awk '1;END{printf "xxx"}' input_file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file input_file
```

Or you can do so with python3 as well:

```
$ cat -A input.txt                                                                                    
line1$

$ python3 -c "import sys;fd=open(sys.argv[1],'a');fd.write('xxx');fd.close()" input.txt               

$ cat -A input.txt                                                                                    
line1$
xxx
```